# Problema com limites da matriz

Tags: c#, array

Boa tarde! Estou fazendo exercicios de vetores e encontrei um problema onde nao entendo.

O problema proposto era colocar valores em um vetor A e B de tamanho 5, e depois juntar esses valores num vetor C de tamanho 10. Desse jeito: A {1,2,3,4,5} B {6,7,8,9,10} C{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

Porém aparece que o indice extrapola os limites da matriz, mesmo eu colocando 800 como leitura como consta o codigo abaixo.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] vetorA = new int[5];
    int[] vetorB = new int[5];
    int[] vetorC = new int[10];

   //Colocando valores no vetorA
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        vetorA[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    //Colocando valores no vetorB
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        vetorB[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    //Colocando os valores de vetorA em vetorC
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        vetorC[i] = vetorA[i];
    }

    //Colocando os valores de vetorB juntamente com vetorA no vetorC
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        vetorC[j + 5] = vetorB[j];
    }

    //lendo e imprimindo os valores do vetorC completo
    for(int x = 0; x < 800; x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(vetorC[x]);
    }


    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: não entendi, você fala em matriz e só apresenta vetores?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, o Visual Studio que fala isso. Eu estou trabalhando somente com vetores, mas quando vou rodar, até aparece corretamente a sequencia, porem na linha:  for(int x = 0; x < 800; x++) o console diz que "extrapolou os limites da matriz", e é exatamente isso a fonte da minha dúvida, pois, primeiro, onde tem matriz ? e segundo, porque extrapolou sendo que coloquei um limite de 800 quando eu so preciso de 10?

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu... "coloquei um limite de 800 quando só precisava de 10"... O que acontece quando você vai abrir a 800ª gaveta de um armário que só tem 10? A mesma coisa que já aconteceria ao tentar abrir a 11ª... ela não existe! E são essas instruções que você está dando para o seu programa.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Eu refiz o programa em outro arquivo do visual, dessa vez colocando i < 10, (no outro programa  i < 10 tambem estava dando erro) e deu certo. Muito obrigado mesmo pela atenção e explicação!

Comment: Mas não é só mudar um numero e funcionar, você precisa entender o que está fazendo, olhe a resposta da pergunta que a sua foi marcada como duplicada

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Eu sou novo na programação e no stack, muito obrigado por ter me chamado atenção pra leitura em que foi marcado como duplicado, consegui resolver mais exercicios com o entendimento, que era fraco, com a questão dos limites, eu estava confundindo o 0 com 1 de vetor e por isso errava na hora de definir o limite.